# How to install solc of a specific version?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, golang

I want to install solc 0.4.24 but the  commands given below installs the new version.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install solc`
Or
`sudo snap install solc`

`solc --version` gives :

> Version: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Linux.g++

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible or not to install solc with a version?
If yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

You're installing the last version from `apt`.

It's much easy to install the specific version of `solc` with docker, here is an example:

```
## Download Docker image
docker pull ethereum/solc:0.4.24

## Usage: docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/root ethereum/solc:0.4.24 <command_here>
# To generate ABI file from .sol file and send output to ./build folder
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/root ethereum/solc:0.4.24 --abi /root/Store.sol -o /root/build
```

[`Here is you can find more info`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#docker)